# adding the current url as param to the redirect url in meta tag using jstl tags

Tags: html, jstl, meta-tags, http-equiv

On a page i am redirecting the user to another page in the meta tag pf my page.

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=/abc/example" />
```

Now i want to add the current page url as a param to the redirect url so that it becomes

```
url = '/abc/example?prevUrl=currentPage.html'
```

I am using jstl tags, trying something like

```
<c:url value = "/abc/example" var="myURL">
    <c:param name="prevUrl" value = document.URL/>
</c:url>

<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url='${myURL}'" />
```

But obviously im doing something wrong. Please help.  Or any other way to add a param to my redirect url???

Comment: What are you processing page requests with on the server side, just a servlet?

Comment: yes. i listen on a servlet and redirecting

Answer (score 0):

In your servlet put the URL on the request like this:

```
request.setAttribute("myUrl", "/abc/example?prevUrl=currentPage.html");
```

Then you can just put it in the meta tag using an EL expression like this:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url='${myUrl}'" />
```